# How to fix The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')

While EAS build(IOS) I am getting this error. Please help me to fix this issue. I am going EAS build because my EXPO app uses the stripe payment method.

Comment: Try to change iOS deployment target to ios 9 in project setting : all devices running iOS 8 will run iOS 8. So this will not be a real problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed to 9 but previously it was 11. But still I have this error

Comment: Did you changed the target deployment ? See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/WorkingwithTargets.html)

Comment: Yes there also it is 9. Now I have changed everything to 12 to test

Comment: did you try to find 8.0 in all your project ?